# how to copy a dashboard in a different azure devops instance?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-dashboard

I have a requirement to copy an existing dashboard dashboard in an org(source org) to a different org(target org) under a different ado instance by any means possible. Dashboard can have widgets and widgets can be linked to

1. pipeline
2. Query - A query can be referencing to a user, team, project, custom values of a standard field, custom fields
3. some other things that i have not encountered so far

So far my steps are as follows

1. get dashboard details using get dashboard rest api
2. identify widgets in dashboard details api response
3. get any pipeline if there is no pipeline create a dummy one and use its details for a widget that is using pipeline
4. identify distinct queries present in all widgets
5. create its equivalent query in target org and save its id
6. replace  queryid  in widget settings to its equivalent created queryid in targetorg
7. create dashboard in target org

I am facing issue in step 5
There are lot of moving variables in a query. Query might be referencing to things that does not exist in target org like a particular user, team, custom values of a standard field, custom fields. In order to create a query successfully i need to know possible values of a field in target org.  While creating a new query from ui it shows possible values for a field in dropdown so i am wondering is there any rest api that gives possible values of a field and if no such field exist in target org then it should throw error.

Looking forward to suggestions for a simpler or alternative approach to replicate a dashboard across different ado instance and/or better approach for step 5

Comment: Hi Gourav, did my post help with your issue?

Comment: Hi Ceeno, It helped. However, i am using list workitemtypes to know fields for all workitems https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a rest api the query the fields in your target process of the organization, you could refer to this doc. [Field-list.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/fields?api-version=6.0-preview.2`

After that, you could create the fields in your target process, you could refer to this rest api. [Fields-Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processdefinitions/fields/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP)

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processdefinitions/{processId}/fields?api-version=4.1-preview.1`

Or could you share more details of your requirement, like screenshots and widget definition or dashboards configuration for update.